# How can I lookup based on multiple parameters?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dict = {
        "AA": {"Rad": 1000.0, "Code": "C01"},
        "BB": {"Rad": 2200.0, "Code": "C02"},
        "CC": {"Rad": 2300.0, "Code": "C02"},
        "DD": {"Rad": 3000.0, "Code": "C04"}
    }
```

Most of the time, selecting the appropriate value is quite simple. My code grabs the value from the dictionary entry by passing in the key and the property I need. For example, if my value is "CC", I get the code with `dict["CC"]["Code"]`. Simple enough and works the vast majority of the time.

Now, I need to adjust for a change in the business logic. If I follow what I've done in the past, the dictionary will look like this:

```
dict = {
        "AA": {"Rad": 1000.0, "Code": "C01"},
        "BB": {"Rad": 2200.0, "Code": "C02"},
        "CC": {"Rad": 2300.0, "Code": "C02"},
        "DD": {"Rad": 3000.0, "Code": "C04"},
        "DD": {"Rad": 7000.0, "Code": "C03"}
    }
```

But this doesn't work. Two identical keys in a dictionary doesn't work. This is problem one.

The other issue, I need to take into account the value of `Rad` when selecting a `Code`. Rad is a minimum value used for comparison. If the value in my variable is greater than `Rad` use corresponding the `Code` value.

How do I restructure this to accommodate value retrieval by dictionary key (the majority of what this code does) and retrieval by `key` & `Rad` value? If necessary, I can through out this dictionary structure and do something different.

Update 2: Refining the business logic a bit. The rad values specified in the dictionary are minimum values. I need to grab the smallest value that is greater than the minimum value regardless of the order in which they are listed in the dictionary.

In the following case,

```
"DD": [{"Rad": 3000.0, "Code": "C04"},
       {"Rad": 7000.0, "Code": "C03"},
       {"Rad": 4000.0, "Code": "C09"}]]
```

`get(d, "DD", 5000)` returns `C04` but `C09` is expected.

Update 1: A database of any kind is way overkill for this project. This dictionary will, at most, have six entries.

Here is the minimal code to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

```
dict = {
        "AA": {"Rad": 1000.0, "Code": "C01"},
        "BB": {"Rad": 2200.0, "Code": "C02"},
        "CC": {"Rad": 2300.0, "Code": "C02"},
        "DD": {"Rad": 3000.0, "Code": "C04"},
        "DD": {"Rad": 7000.0, "Code": "C03"}
    }

type = "DD"
rad = 4000

# need to incorporate rad variable
print dict["type"]["Code"]  

# Should print C04
```

Comment: You might want to consider using an actual database for this type of queries. `sqlite` is built-in to Python and would be a good choice

Comment: What should be the result of `dict['DD']['Code']`?

Comment: if you use a pair as key `{ ('dd', 'rad') : { ... }}`

Comment: but you dict don't have rad 4000

Comment: @JuanPablo That is correct. the value of rad needs to be compared against the values in dict. The values in the dict are minimum values. 4000 is greater than 3000 so the return should be C04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the values in your dictionary lists, so one key can be mapped to multiple values.

```
d = {
        "AA": [{"Rad": 1000.0, "Code": "C01"}],
        "BB": [{"Rad": 2200.0, "Code": "C02"}],
        "CC": [{"Rad": 2300.0, "Code": "C02"}],
        "DD": [{"Rad": 3000.0, "Code": "C04"}, {"Rad": 7000.0, "Code": "C03"}]
    }
```

For getting the `code` from the list satisfying the `rad` constraint, you could try this:

```
def get(d, t, r):
    try:
        return max((x for x in d[t] if x["Rad"] < r), key=lambda x: x["Rad"])["Code"]
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Example:

```
>>> get(d, "DD", 4000)
C04
```

Comment: @DenaliHardtail Why is `C09` expected? Do you want the highest value that's just below `rad`? If so, please add this to the question. I'll edit the answer...

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to structure your dictionary like this:

```
dict = {
    "AA": {1000.0: "C01"},
    "BB": {2200.0: "C02"},
    "CC": {2300.0: "C02"},
    "DD": {3000.0: "C04",
           7000.0: "C03"},
}
```

Then to get a the `Code` field, you can write `dict["AA"][1000.0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Are the sub-dictionaries always going to have the same two fields? If so, you could place the "Rad" and "Code" fields into a tuple, then put the tuples into a list, like:

```
dict = {
            "AA": [(1000.0, "C01")]
            ...
            "DD": [(3000.0,"C04"), (7000.0, "C03")]

       }
```

To access the "Code" field of the first entry for the "DD" field, use:

```
dict["DD"][0][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {
        ...
        "DD": {4000:{"code":"C04"}, 7000: {"Code": "C03"}}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom type class to do that.

```
import itertools
import bisect

class cdict(dict):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        dict.__init__(self)
        if data: self.update(data)

    def __call__(self,base,target):
        res = self.get(base) if base else None
        _st = res.items() if isinstance(res,dict) else res
        if isinstance(res,dict):
            if res and target:
                _item = res['Rad']
                if target >= _item: return res['Code']
        elif isinstance(res,list):
            _iter = sorted ( filter (lambda x: not isinstance(x,str),list (itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(lambda x: x.values(),res)))))
            if len(res) and target:
                _filter = filter (lambda x: x <= target,_iter)
                _sorted =  bisect.bisect(_filter,target)
                if len(_filter) and not _sorted: return filter (lambda x: x['Rad'] == _iter [ _sorted ],res)[0]['Code']
                elif len(_filter) and _sorted: return filter (lambda x: x['Rad'] == _iter [ _sorted -1 ],res)[0]['Code']
        return None

x = cdict({
    "AA": {"Rad": 1000.0, "Code": "C01"},
    "BB": {"Rad": 2200.0, "Code": "C02"},
    "CC": {"Rad": 2300.0, "Code": "C02"},
    "DD": [ {"Rad": 7000.0, "Code": "C04"}, {"Rad": 3000.0, "Code": "C03"} ] } )

print x('AA',2000.0)
print x('DD',8000.0)
print x('DD',4000.0)
```

C01
C04
C03